# Big-O time complexity of recursive algorithm with nested for loops

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I have a recursive algorithm with two nested for loops.  I'm trying to figure out what the Big-O time complexity will be.

```
public Set<Person> getDistinctCombinedPersons(Collection<Person> persons) {
  return permutatePersons(new ArrayList(persons), new HashSet<>(persons));
}
```

---

```
private Set<Person> permutatePersons(List<Person> personList, Set<Person> personSet) {
  if(personList.isEmpty() {
    return personSet;
  }

  Set<Person> deepCopyPersonSet = new HashSet<>(personSet);

  for(Person lPerson : personList) {
    for(Person sPerson : deepCopyPersonSet) {
      Person uniquePerson = CombinePeople.combine(lPerson, sPerson);
      personSet.add(uniquePerson);
    }
  }

  personList.remove(personList.size()-1);

  return permutatePersons(personList, personSet);
}
```

Comment: (By the way, "deep copy" doesn't mean what you think it does.)

Comment: @ruakh yea I should have just said clone

Comment: @ruakh What is the Big-O complexity of my algorithm

Comment: I might be wrong here but it looks like `O(n^ n+2)`.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can just remove the outer for loop somehow?

Comment: Few hypothesis are missing to be able to estimate the complexity, e.g. 1) is the operation `CombinePeople` O(1)? 2) Is I have two persons `a` and `b`, does `combine(a, b)` produces a new person which is different from every other persons, included in the existing set and the ones to come? This is important because we need to know by how much the `personSet` is growing at each step of the recursion.

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez 1) yea 2) it can produce a unique person, but doesn't have to.

Comment: @Grammin ok, and what is the best assumption we can draw about the increase of the size of `personSet` after the double `for` loop if `permutatePersons` is called with a list of `n` persons and a set of `m` unique persons? Is it `m + n*m`? If so, the person set grows exponentially over the recursion, and a lower bound of the complexity of your algorithm would be `n` to the power of `n`. Again, the key of this analysis is to know by how many records `personSet` increases at each iteration. Actually it would help if you published the source code for `Person` and `CombinePerson`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you call `permutatePersons` with a list of length `N` the following recursion applies:

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + O(N^2)
```

That's because in every recursive step you call function with list of length N-1 (where N the current length) and also you do computations of total complexity O(N^2) (outer loop O(N) -just traversing list and inner loop traversing the hash map in O(N) -O(1) for each element and total N element, So the nested loops are overall O(N^2)).

You can easily see:

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + O(N^2) = T(N-2) + O(N^2) + O((N-1)^2) =...

= O(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6) = O(n^3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. I'm now wonder if I take out the outer for loop is the algorithm still doing the same thing?

Comment: In terms of complexity no it will be reduced in `O(N^2)` due to the recursion now will be: `T(N)= T(N-1) + O(N)`.

Comment: Yea I'm wondering though if my algorithm is the exact same if I remove the outer for loop just less complex

Comment: No if I understand correctly what you're trying to do-to generate all 2-combinations of persons you need two loops-O(N^2) and O(N^3) overall...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it would be a big-O of n^2 for the nested loop:

```
  for(Person lPerson : personList) {
    for(Person sPerson : deepCopyPersonSet) {
      Person uniquePerson = CombinePeople.combine(lPerson, sPerson);
      personSet.add(uniquePerson);
    }
  }
```

You have to iterate over the each element for each element in the set.

And then the recursive call has a big O of n since it will call your method once for each element in the set.

Combining the two: `n * n^2` will result in a **big O of n^3**

Comment: What effect does the recursion have?

Comment: @jhpratt I don't this the method is using any recursion unless I'm missing something. Do you mean iteration?

Comment: Nope, the last line is a recursive call.

Comment: I also have the recursive call in there too

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two nested loops you have the runtime complexity of `O(m*n)`. It's because for `n`-`Person`s in `deepCopyPersonSet` you iterate `m` times. `n` in this example is the quantity of `Person`s in `personList`.

Your code is basically:

```
for(int i = 0, i < m, i++)
  for(int j = 0, j < n, j++)
    //your code
```

For every iteration of m, we have n iterations of code

Comment: I also have the recursive call in there too